# Why does this output "nan" (lua)

Tags: lua

[this outputs "nan" on the last section of code "thC" section, ive searched for fixes and tried converting to number directly and ect, i am quite new but i dont understand this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtjn.png)

[info regarding "a b and c" (test values that caused the "nan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8siuX.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: i changed the "thc" in the acos of the C section to a test value and it still outputs nan

Comment: fixed by Gabriel, acos was larger than 1, -1, i wasent using radians for my last SSS angle

Comment: next time ill provide text instead of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original: Due to the lack of information regarding the values of a, b, c, the most probable answer is that **a**, **c** or **b** are 0, thus converting the operations results to NaN, because you *cannot* divide by 0.

Reviewed: After testing out your code, the NaN occurs because you can only use values between [-1, 1] as arguments for the Math.Acos() method.

Take a look at the documentation of the methods you use in order to avoid this kind of errors happening in the future: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

Comment: will look into this and try :) thanks!

Comment: i can send info of a b and c tho

Comment: i tested and it seems to be a problem with the "acos"

Comment: Updated the answer to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping i will use this and fix my issue :)